# How should I query MySQL and how to cache the results from MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have managed finally to get Solr working, with the help of all you guys, so THANK YOU!
And I have to say, I now understand why you recommended it, it's really powerful.

Now, to the issue...

I have indexed all "Searchable" information into `Solr`, and my plan is to query Solr, and then get the `ID:s` of the query-results (of all records that is, each has an ID field value), which I then use to `query MySQL` and fetch the rest of the information.
So, first query Solr, next solr sends back id:s for all ads which match the query, then I use the ID:s to query MySQL for the rest of the info.

My Q is, When doing the part with MySql, should I save all the received ID:s into an `array`, and then `query mysql` to find all records with those ID:s?
Should I do something like this? (might contain some code errors):

```
       for ($i=0; $i<$id_from_solr.length; $i++){
       mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ad_id=$id_from_solr[$i]");
       }
```

The above seems **not** like a good solution, because it does a "new query" everytime it loops again!

How would you do it?

**Follow-up Question:**
Would adding a sort function into the MySQL query slow things down compared to WITHOUT using the sort function? for example:

```
      ORDER BY insert_date ASC
```

**And last Q:**
Is there anyway to cache MySQL results so when sorting, I don't have to make a new query?

Thanks alot!

If you need more input, let me know and I will update this Q!

Comment: If the query is slow with the _ORDER BY_, try addind an INDEX on that coulomb.

Comment: I think you meant "cache" rather than "catch" - I've made this edit for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1** (retrieving IDs and then querying the database): why not return some of your fields from the Solr query so that you don't always have to hit the database as well?

**Q2** (Performance and sorting): well, sorting represents an extra task to perform on your data, so it is bound to add a bit of work for the database: this can of course be minimized if you have an index on your `ORDER BY` column(s).

**Q3** (catching MySql queries): you can either turn on the MySql cache (which will return a cached copy of your results if the request matched a previous one, assuming the data has not been changed in the interim), or use a caching layer outside of the database, such as EhCache:

http://ehcache.org/

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, here's how I would write a single query statement:

```
$instr=implode(", ",$id_from_solr);
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ad_id IN (".$instr.")";
```